# how to clear value in vf as well as in apex controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

after clicking clear button i want to clear the input text value.Now it's clearing fine.But the value remains same in the controller.It is not reflected in the apex.
    how to do this ?

```
vf:

 <apex:outputPanel id="showblock" style="display:none;">
          <div id="clearFilterDiv">
           <apex:pageblockSection columns="3">
            <apex:repeat value="{!filterArray}" var="a">
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!a.label}"/>
                  <apex:inputText value="{!a.SearchValue}" id="searchTextId"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
              </apex:repeat> 
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
               <apex:outputPanel id="outptText">
                 <a href="#" onClick="clearValue()" id="clearValue" style="display:none;"> Clear Filter </a>
               </apex:outputPanel> 
                 <apex:commandButton value="Apply Filter" onclick="filterSearch();return false;"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
              </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>


script
 function clearValue() {
        $("[id$=searchTextId]").val('');

    }
```

Comment: Why can't you use a simple pagecommandbutton, on click of that call a method in apex which empties the string. Like clearmethod(){searchstring = '';}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your javascript function you are clearing the value from the page , from clear the value from class just add **action** to the button and in that action clear the values from the class also.

in clearvalue function you can clear the variable value from class itself.

Comment: Actually it is commandlink and also i have tried that too by using action function I am calling a method in controller and setting the input text value as null . Still the result is same

Comment: the after clearing the value from javascript you can call <apex:actionfunction>,and from action function you can call call method to clear the values.

Comment: thats the thing i tried. Here is my code : 

 public void actionFunMethod() {
    
  
    
    filterArray=null;
        
    
    } 

<a href="#" onClick="clearValue()" id="clearValue" style="display:none;"> Clear Filter
                    <apex:actionFunction name="caall" action="{!actionFunMethod}"/> 
                     </a>

Comment: have you debug actionFunMethod method is it calling from Page??

Comment: thans Avijit. It worked as exactly you suggested !!!

Comment: Also you can upvote so that other can find the answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code in place of yours :

```
function clearValue() {
    document.getElementById('myPageId:mnFrmId:mnPgBlkId:myEmlId').value = '';

}
```

PS: the 'myPageId:mnFrmId:mnPgBlkId:myEmlId' is the id of the input text box. So please provide your id of the input text box which you want to clear.

Please refer the below VF page as an example for this :

```
<apex:page controller="MyClearTextBoxClass" id="myPageId">

<Script>
    var myValidate = function(){}
    myValidate = function(){
        var getEmailVal = document.getElementById("myPageId:mnFrmId:mnPgBlkId:myEmlId").value;
        CallControlMeth();
    }

    function clearValue() {
        document.getElementById('myPageId:mnFrmId:mnPgBlkId:myEmlId').value = '';

    }
</script>   
<apex:form id="mnFrmId">
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!checkEmail}" name="CallControlMeth"/>
        <apex:pageBlock id="mnPgBlkId">
            <table id="TblId">
                <tr id="1stTrId">
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText > Email Address: </apex:outputText>
                    </td>
                    <td id="inpuTMailID">
                        <apex:inputText id="myEmlId" value="{!email}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="2ndTrId">
                    <td>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Click me!" reRender="mnFrmId" onclick="myValidate()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="outptText">
                        <a href="#" onClick="clearValue()" id="clearValue" style="display:block;"> Clear Filter </a>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing class MyClearTextBoxClass {
    public String email{get;set;}

    //contructor
    public MyClearTextBoxClass (){

    }

    public PageReference checkEmail() {
        //Do some task
        System.debug('@@@@ email:'+email);

        PageReference myPage;
        myPage = new PageReference('/006/o');
        return myPage;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should never  hardcode these "j_id0:mnFrmId:mnPgBlkId:myEmlId" ids!

Comment: @partha, the values is getting cleared in client side , but not in server side (controller). That's what i am facing difficulty

Comment: @ram135868 , When you will set the value from your script to blank( as show in the above example), and call your controller method after that , it will automatically reset your value to blank. Please try the above example and check your debug. Once it is reset and then the controller method is called( let say we are saving it) it will flash out the value .