# How to empty a pageblock section?

Tags: pageblocksection

I have this page block section code:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="contactData" columns="2" collapsible="true" >
   <apex:outputText label="First Name" value="{!p.FirstName}"           id="contFN"/>
   <apex:outputText label="Mailing Street" value="{!p.MailingStreet}"       id="contMailingStreet"/>
//...many more outputTest
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

There is a method on JS that I need to empty all the output Texts. I tried styleclass to put an empty value to each output Text but it doesn't work. How should I do it? like $('.contactFields').val(''); wont work here. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why don't you use `apex:inputfield` or `apex:inputText` if you want to clear those values.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try something like this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/172721/10073

    function clearValues() {
            document.getElementById('contactData:contFN').value = '';
            document.getElementById('contactData:contMailingStreet').value = '';

        }
```